# Would (or should) CDI provide package qualifiers?

Tags: java, cdi, qualifiers, deltaspike

Studying Seam 3, I discovered that Seam Solder allows the `@Named` annotation to be applied to packages - in that case, all beans in this package will be automatically named, as if they were qualified with `@Named` themselves. I didn't see too much advantages on doing something like this (and you can point me some situations where it can be useful!) but it made me wonder: wouldn't it be reasonable to CDI (or Seam Solder) to allow arbitrary qualifiers to be applied to packages as well, maintaining the same semantics of this `@Named` qualifier? Is it a possible functionality in future versions of the CDI specification? Is there a reason for *not* allowing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't see too much advantages on doing something like this (and you
>   can point me some situations where it can be useful!)

`@Named` (as you certainly know) makes a managed bean accessible from within JSF pages. Applied on package level it will simply assign an EL name to all beans in that package. While I agree with you that this is certainly not a killer feature, I can imagine that quite often everything within a certain package needs to be accessed via EL. Of course it's another question if annotating all beans individually wouldn't be better in terms of readability.

> wouldn't it be reasonable to CDI (or Seam Solder) to allow arbitrary
>   qualifiers to be applied to packages as well, maintaining the same
>   semantics of this @Named qualifier?

`@SomeQualifier` would apply the same qualifier to all beans in the package. Contrary to `@Named` I can hardly imagine that this would make much sense - looking back on a couple of CDI projects in the last year, I think I never had a package where all beans in it required the same qualifier. Kind of makes extra sense if you remember that qualifiers are meant for *loose coupling* of components... (Say you have an interface with three implementations - almost certainly those would belong into different packages or even jars)

Comment: I would hardly use `@Named` in a package given the point you cited: readability.  OTOH, I can realize a package with various close implementations (let's say, `LDAPAuthenticator`, `LDAPQuery`, `LDAPConnector`) for various related interfaces (`Authenticator`, `Query`, `Connector`). In this case, I would happily qualify the package - even because the own package would document the "LDAP nature" of the classes. Doesn't it sound reasonable? BTW, I do not know the `@SomeQualifier` - do you have any link about it?

Comment: Hm. I see. I personally would discourage such a methodology (IMHO it's dangerously close to "I'm grouping my classes in a certain way for the only reason that it saves me a qualifer"), plus the ldap-nature of the bean types could already be expressed by the type name itself and/or corresponding package name. Anyhow, such a thing should be relatively easy achievable through a CDI extension (scan bean types at startup and see if any package-qualifiers are to be applied)... Oh, `@SomeQualifer` is documented next to `@IJustNeededAQualiferNameForTheExample` :-)

Comment: Ah, now everything makes sense about this revolutionary annotation :) BTW, the way I purposed to organize my beans is the way I feel the more natural, personally. I would never use it just to avoid some annotations. Anyway, I think you gave me a good answer about why people do not think a lot about qualifying packages. More opinions would be welcomed but your answer is accepted :)